# How to render React Objects with useState from a separat file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, use-state

this is my data "personell.js"

```
export const personell = [
  {
    name: " Andrew",
  },
  {
    name: " Josh",
  },
  {
    name: "Eric",
  },
];
```

And I want to render it through my App function

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { personell } from "./Personell";

function App() {
  console.log(personell);
  const [person, setPerson] = useState([personell]);

  const Person = ({ persons }) => <h1 className="persons">{persons.name}</h1>;

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="personell-list">
        {person.map((persons, index) => (
          <Person key={index} index={index} persons={persons} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

that way nothing is being rendered, though using console.log works fine

Or is there maybe a more efficient to do that?

Comment: 1) The Person component should be pulled out of the App function 2) Name your variables more intuitively... an array should be plural and individual elements should be singular.

Comment: I will note it down thank you
I just wanted to make a quick recreation of my problem, thats why it looks so messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting an array, and then putting that array in another array:

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState([personell]);
```

To get it to work you just need to do

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState(personnell);
```

As pointed out in comments also, your naming does confuse it a little bit with `person` and `setPerson` meaning singular, but you are providing a collection of people.

Comment: Yeah I see  that sorry for the confusion, but thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your useState is wrong! Set it as:

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState(personell);
```

it should work.